# Can I save an image to a specific album with the camera roll when saving via writeImageToSavedPhotosAlbum:metadata:completionBlock:?

Tags: iphone, image, camera, uiimagepickercontroller, photos

I have an app that edits a photo's exif data then saves that image to the camera roll via:

```
[library writeImageToSavedPhotosAlbum:[newTestImage CGImage] metadata:metadata completionBlock:^(NSURL *assetURL, NSError *error) {
    //error
}];
```

This works fine, but is there a way that I can save the image to a specific (ideally new) album within the camera roll? I have searched extensively here and elsewhere and I'm aware of addAssetsGroupAlbumWithName: but as that won't add the new image metadata I don't think I can use it.

Thanks for any help.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There is a great category out there that helps you easily save a photo to a custom album.

Here it is on GitHub

https://github.com/Kjuly/ALAssetsLibrary-CustomPhotoAlbum

You'll need to make some adjustments to support saving the metadata as well, but it should be as simple as replacing the above code's use of

```
- (void)writeImageToSavedPhotosAlbum:(CGImageRef)imageRef orientation:(ALAssetOrientation)orientation completionBlock:(ALAssetsLibraryWriteImageCompletionBlock)completionBlock
```

and using this instead after passing in the metadata

```
- (void)writeImageToSavedPhotosAlbum:(CGImageRef)imageRef metadata:(NSDictionary *)metadata completionBlock:(ALAssetsLibraryWriteImageCompletionBlock)completionBlock
```

Comment: Hi bbodayle, not sure if this is bad stackoverflow etiquette, but really appreciated how promptly and accurately you answered my last question, don't suppose you'd have any ideas about this one? http://stackoverflow.com/questions/13439549/is-it-possible-to-share-an-image-via-uiactivityviewcontroller-and-retain-exif-da